# Add "or tutorial" to off-topic close reason

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, close-reasons

There are very many questions asking practically for guidance, tutorial or spoonfeeding. Answering such questions would require namely to give link to some tutorial, however off-site resource are off topic:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite
>   off-site** resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Just adding "or tutorial" to that phrase would be fine:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library, tutorial
>   or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: tutorials really count as off-site resources, don't they?

Comment: @JanDvorak I think so and I've used that close reason in that way. But I think it would be good to make it more clear for OP.

Comment: @JanDvorak it really comes down to "do we want to increase the text length to make it more explicit?"

Comment: We could always remove the word "favorite." I never really understood why that word was in there. Whether or not you're asking for someone's favorite off-site resource doesn't make the question less off-topic...